# Having an error in my SQL syntax when trying to use joins

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm currently trying to do this `sql` query, but I'm not the greatest at SQL:

```
var sqlQuery = `
    SELECT user.ID, user.email, user.first_name, user.last_name,
    user.address1, user.address2, user.country, user.gender  
    FROM subscriber AS user 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT sID, name, experience, locked  
        FROM chars
    ) AS char 
      ON user.ID = char.sID 
    WHERE user.ID = ?
`;
```

But I get this error:

```
[1] Errors  { [Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'char
[1]           ON user.ID = char.sID
[1]         WHERE user.ID = 13' at line 4]
[1]   code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
[1]   errno: 1064,
[1]   sqlState: '42000',
[1]   index: 0 }
```

Any information would be great thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Char` is a reserved keyword, which can be looked up at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html.

So changing the code to this, does the trick. In general stay away from variable  names that conflicts with data types.

```
( SELECT sID, name, experience, locked  
FROM chars ) AS c
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax would be LEFT JOIN chars as char

```
var sqlQuery = `
SELECT user.ID, user.email, user.first_name, user.last_name,
user.address1, user.address2, user.country, user.gender  
FROM subscriber AS user 
LEFT JOIN chars AS char 
  ON user.ID = char.sID 
WHERE user.ID = ?
```

Why did you want the name, experience and locked fields anyway?

Comment: As martin says, char is a reserver keyword... So instead char, it would be "c"